# Validating incremental or repeating input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to write a validation function with jQuery to validate a phone number against an incremental (for example 12345 or 56789) or repeating (for example 11111 or 22222) input but am out of ideas on how to do that. Could anybody give me an idea on how this can be done?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? You could potentially prevent 15 people from using your service.

Comment: And what if my number is 1234-567, hm..

Comment: incremental number means lower or upper limit something will be there regular expressions are the one you might be looking

Comment: If you want to actually "validate" phone numbers, send them a sms or automated voice call or something with a confirmation code, otherwise there isn't much point to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this to validate either repeating (i.e. 55555) or incremental (i.e. 123456) numbers

```
function validateNum(input){
    var value=input.val(), len=value.length, first=value[0], r=true;
    if(!len || isNaN(value) || value==0) return false;
    for( var i=1; i<len; i++ )
    {
        if(value[i]!=first) { r=false; break; }
        //else continue;
    }
    if(r) return true;
    r=true;       
    for( var i=1; i<len; i++ )
    {
        if(value[i]!=(parseInt(first)+i)) { r=false; break; }
        //else continue;
    }
    if(r) return true;
    return false;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jdSu8/5/).

Comment: I'd personally prefer returning `false` for failed validations and `true` for valid ones, and the second loop doesn't seem necessary (if `+value[1] !== +first+1` then it won't be a sequential value after all), but good work +1

Comment: Great answer and one I'll be using - though it does not account for decremental numbers (I guess that wasn't the OPs question).  Just a warning to those who're using this, it does repeating and incremental perfectly, but does not account for decremental -- Still +1